# How do I create a Word file from InDesign which recognises footnotes?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, microsoft-word

I've designed a book completely in InDesign. However, I want to delegate the job to others to continue adding to the book. It would be costly in terms of time and money to purchase and teach InDesign to these designers and for the purposes of the book it would be fine if it was made in Word. Therefore I would like to convert the InDesign file to an editable Word file.

Now, I've tried creating both interactive as well as print pdfs from the InDesign file. I have then converted each pdf into Word but found that the footnotes were converted to plain text in Word and placed at the bottom of the respective pages. Is there a way to create a Word file so that Word recognises the superscripted numbers and appended texts as footnote numbers and text? For example, is there a specific pdf preset which would allow this?

Comment: Never heard this one before. What a headache. Using PDF seems like a dead end. Had to google and it revealed [this plugin](http://emsoftware.com/products/wordsflow/). Don't know anything about it though.

Comment: There is no direct InDesign to Word path which I am aware of. The*best* one can often do is Indesign -> PDF -> Word as you've done. However, *you get what you get*. Expecting more advanced InDesign features to survive any migration to poor software such as Word is sort of expecting miracles. (Comment on the plug in @Wolff linked to.. not really certain it's needed. There's a link option already in InDesign for Word files.. but that's Word -> INDD... not the reverse. The plug in seems to merely enhance the Word to INDD path, not reverse it.)

Comment: @Scott, under the heading "Pro is two-way" they claim that "Additionally, the Pro version can export original InDesign story content in Word DOCX format". Whetherit works with footnotes or not, I haven't looked into.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I will see what I can do with just the Word file.